# How do i update prices with view for admin ? My rates changes overtime. how do i allow the admin to update them and display to users accordingly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here are my codes, im using asp.net Web applications MVC

Basically just need allow admin/superuser to be able to update the rates for membership 'in those 2 textboxes names lifetime and yearlyrates and it will display in "Prices" in a non-admin view when clicked on the duration for membership renewal. Would be great if someone can help me with these codes.

This is the view that allows admin to update the prices for yearly and lifetime membership rates

```
 @model RenewMember
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Membership Renewal";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    string msg = ViewData["msg"] as string;

    var Duration = new[]
    {
        new { value=1, text="1 year"},
        new { value=2, text="2 years"},
        new { value=3, text="3 years"},
        new { value=4, text="Life-time"}
    };

    @section ScriptSection {
        <script>
            function DisplayPrice() {
                var price1yearmember = 100;
                var rate = 1;
                var subtotal = 0;
                if (selectedCurrency == "USD") {
                    subtotal = price1yearmember * rateUSD;
                }
                else if (selectedCurrency == "MYR") {
                    subtotal = price1yearmember * rateMYR;
                }
                else if (selectedCurrency == "SGD") {
                    subtotal = price1yearmember * rate;
                }
                $("#txtPrice").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
            }

        </script>
    }
}

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/lib/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&#038;render=explicit&#038;ver=2.0'></script>

    <style>
        <style > .input-group-addon {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #BsDateTimePicker {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#BsDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/src/core.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #head {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            font-style: oblique;
            font-size: larger;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            will-change: contents;
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        #late {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: larger;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            will-change: contents;
        }

        .field-validation-error {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
            /*background-color: yellow;*/
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            font-style: unset;
            font-size: medium;
        }

        .validation-summary-errors {
            border: 2px dashed red;
            color: red;
            /*background-color: yellow;*/
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="RenewMember">

    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))
    {

        <div class="form-group">
            <label input id="txtYearRate" class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="YearlyRate">Rates per year : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="YearlyRate" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="has-error">
                <span asp-validation-for="YearlyRate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label input id="txtLifeRate" class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="LifeRate">Rates for Lifetime membership : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="LifeRate" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            <div class="has-error">
                <span asp-validation-for="LifeRate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
    else
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="Email">Email : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="has-error">
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="RenewDuration">Duration : </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @foreach (var freq in Duration)
                {
                    <input type="radio" asp-for="RenewDuration" value="@freq.value" /> @freq.text
                }
            </div>
            <div class="has-error">
                <span asp-validation-for="RenewDuration" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Price: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right:15px;">
                <input id="txtPrice" class="form-control" value="-" readonly disabled style="background-color:#C0C0C0" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left:0">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("_CurrencySelector");
                }
            </div>
        </div>

                    }

@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperUser"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Renew" />
        </div>
    </div>

}


</form>
```

This is my model code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PSS.Models
{
    public class RenewMember
{


    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 4, ErrorMessage = "Please select a Duration for renewal")]
    public int RenewDuration { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    public int YearlyRate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    public int LifeRate { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public float CurrencyRate { get; set; }
}
}
```

And this will be my controller which has nothing much in it yet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PSS.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using MimeKit;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace PSS.Controllers
{
public class RenewMemberController : Controller
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public RenewMemberController(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // DbSet<RenewMember> dbs = _dbContext.RenewMember;
        //var lstType =
        //  dbs.ToList<RenewMember>()
        //   .OrderBy(p => p.TypeName)
        // .Select(
        //   p =>
        // {
        //   dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        // d.value = p.MemberTypeId;
        //d.text = p.TypeName;
        //return d;
        // }
        // )
        //.ToList<dynamic>();
        //ViewData["currency"] = lstCurrency;

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

This is what i tried

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateRate(RenewMember rate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DbSet<RenewMember> dbs = _dbContext.RenewMember;
            RenewMember nrate = dbs.Where(m => m.Id == rate.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (rate != null)
            {
                nrate.YearlyRate = rate.YearlyRate;
                nrate.LifeRate = rate.LifeRate;

                string msg = "";
                if (_dbContext.SaveChanges() == 1)
                    msg = String.Format("Rates info updated!");
                TempData["Msg"] = msg;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Rate not found!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = "Invalid information entered";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When i click "Save" button it shows localhost page not found, it redirects me to  "http://localhost:49228/renewmember/RenewMember" which does not exist. My page is suppose to be http://localhost:49228/renewmember/Index. However my database is still not updated.

Comment: Are you just asking how to save data to and read data from a database in ASP.NET MVC?  Any introductory tutorial which includes using a database would cover that.  Have you tried following a few tutorials?  Have you made any attempt?  What have you tried and what specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: this is what i tried

Comment: it doesnt have to be placed into database, it just need to retrieve the value that admin has entered be it databse or not. because the rates changes overtime and the admin can change the rates

Comment: What is this typo: `<style>
        <style > .input-group-addon {`

Comment: Please update the question to show your attempt and to indicate what specifically isn’t working as expected.

Comment: i've updated it

Comment: Consider `<input asp-for="YearlyRate" class="form-control" value="@Model.YearlyRate" />`

Comment: For this scenario, rather than one I would create three views.  One would "contain" the other two, one (partial view) for the Admin, one for "regular" - makes the views simpler to manage, just put the reverence to the partial views inside the conditional.

Comment: DO some cleanup. For example `@section ScriptSection {` can also contain the OTHER script contents, same with style tags.  Better yet, put all those in separate files, one for style (.css) and one for script (.js) named perhaps for the view...

Comment: Yes i tried <input asp-for="YearlyRate" class="form-control" value="@Model.YearlyRate" /> But how do i input the value into the model

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the question, you have it pointing to `RenewMember`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="RenewMember">
```

You might consider different controller methods:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="UpdateAdminMember">
```

and a separate view with different controller method:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-action="SaveNewMember">
```

OR use some helpers

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
```

As for your example for admin (and another partial view for the non-admin view)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAdminMember", "RenewMember", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YearlyRate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YearlyRate)
    ...
}
```